# SQL Server - Alternative to @@ROWCOUNT for checking if UPDATE was made in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQL Server, I have a Stored Procedure that updates a certain column in a table. And it returns a Boolean output parameter depending if it has updated an item in the table or not.

It looks like this.

```
DECLARE @UpdateCount INT

UPDATE dbo.Person
SET Age = 21
WHERE ID = 1

SELECT @UpdateCount = @@ROWCOUNT

IF(@UpdateCount = 1)
  BEGIN
    SET @Output_IsUpdateSuccessful = 1
  END

ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @Output_IsUpdateSuccessful = 0
  END
```

In order to verify if an update was made, I just use @@ROWCOUNT. But I am not sure if this is a reliable way of doing so.

> Is there a general or best practice for checking if an UPDATE has been
>   made in SQL Server?

Comment: An alternative would be to use `OUTPUT...INTO` and then see if there any rows in the table inserted into, however, that would probably need more resources than `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: There's a simpler alternative in this case because you can set the boolean directly: do a `SET @Output_IsUpdateSuccessful = 0` before the statement, and do `SET Age = 21, @Output_IsUpdateSuccessful = 1` in the `UPDATE`. This happens to work out here because you're updating one row and you already have an output parameter -- `@@ROWCOUNT` is the general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is ok, but I would modify the `if` control because the `update` row might be more than one.

```
SELECT @UpdateCount = @@ROWCOUNT

IF(@UpdateCount = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Output_IsUpdateSuccessful = 0
END  
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Output_IsUpdateSuccessful = 1
END
```